# saving attachments (URLs) submitted via a Form into a List

Tags: list, power-automate, form, url, attachments

I have a Form that accepts a file attachment

[image]

which, when submitted, stores the file in the following location

```
https://[domain]/sites/RDTeam/Shared%20Documents/Apps/Microsoft%20Forms/Data%20Request%20(BETA)/Include%20a%20copy%20of%20the%20last%20time%20you%20received%20this/
```

and triggers a Flow that writes the contents of the Form to a List.

[image]

However, placing the corresponding Form object into the Attachment field of the List generates an OpenApiOperationParameterTypeConversionFailed error. As explained [here](https://collab365.com/setting-updating-sharepoint-hyperlink-fields-flow-logic-apps/), this does not work since a List's Hyperlink field type has two parts:

[image]

As a workaround, I have implemented the subsequent HTTP PATCH request as per the above post.

[image]

The Flow now executes without generating an error, but the URL and Description are obviously hard-coded in this example. I'd like this instead to pull from the values submitted through the Form.

My question is: How do I reference the "name" and "link" attributes of the object coming from the Form so that I can dynamically populate the Description and URL values of the JSON for storing something like this [Web Colors.pdf](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=5f32528e7ee71617JmltdHM9MTY2MDU3MzYyMCZpZ3VpZD04ZGRkZGExYi1kNWMyLTQ2MmItOGI3ZS1iZWUyNTI4MDViODcmaW5zaWQ9NTIyMQ&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=52d2d1a1-1ca6-11ed-8e08-293b4947f54a&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudHV0b3JpYWxzcG9pbnQuY29tL2Nzcy9wZGYvY3NzX2NvbG9ycy5wZGY&ntb=1) in the Attachment column of my List?

```
{
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Data_x0020_RequestListItem' },
    'Attachment': {
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldUrlValue' },
        'Description': '[name]',
        'Url': '[link]'
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share more details like how you are storing attachment to SharePoint? May be it would be good if you can share more screen shot of your Flow

Comment: Thanks. I have added more details to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an attachment is an optional Form component in my situation, I need to test for the presence of one.

[image]

To obtain the unique identifier used in the json() expression, I temporarily placed the Form object in question - the one that accepts the uploaded file - into the Create item step (or it could get temporarily placed anywhere for that matter) and hovered over it to view the tool tip.

[image]

In the Apply to each step, I have the following. (There are likely several other ways of accomplishing this.)

[image]

With these changes, the Flow can now dynamically reference (1) the filename and (2) its SharePoint URL as created by the Form submission and, in turn, writes this into the List's Attachment column with the proper values assigned to the two parts of the Hyperlink data type.

[image]